# Why when we run a executable file we need to add ./ ahead?

Tags: bash, executable

Say I have a `somecommands.sh` and I use `chmod 777` to make it executable. Why I have to type `./scommand.sh` instead of typing just `somecommand.sh` to run it from its own directory?

Does this make any sense? If it's able to omit, what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to likely do that, because your current path (`pwd`) is not in your search path for executable files.

Type this in your console:

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
```

Every folder that is printed, is in the search path for executable files (in that order).

Now, if you want to run a file from a *different* directory, you have to supply the full (relative or absolute) path.

```
./script.sh
```

means the current directory (`./`, relative to where you are) and the the filename (`script.sh`). You can equally well use the full path (starting from the root folder `/`) to your file (for instance `/home/guo/script.sh`, if hat's your username, and when your file is in your home directory).

As a tip, if you regularly use that file, I suggest making a local `/bin` directory (`~/bin`, as inside your home directory) and then put `export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` into your `.bashrc`, for instance. And then put your scripts into that directory.

Another thing: I suggest not using **777** as permissions to run it. Instead I suggest **755**, so only you have permission to overwrite the file. If you want to make a file executable just use `chmod +x script.sh`, it'll usually do what you want.

In a similar fashion as I've described above, it *is* possible to add the "current" directory, to path: `export PATH=".:$PATH"`, but this is not advisable. I *strongly* advise, using a private directory (`~/bin`) for those use cases.

Comment: *search path* for executable files is the place that when I put the shell file inside, I can run directly anywhere, right?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo yes.

Answer (score 2):

In order to run any executable in Linux, you need to mention its full path (in case it is not stored in the `$PATH` variable).

In Linux, `.` stands for the directory that you are currently in and `/` is the path separator. So, with `./somecommands.sh`, you tell the shell that, please run the executable `somecommands.sh` which is present in current directory.